# Elementwise comparison of two matrices in Eigen (C++)

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have MatrixXf A & MatrixXf B and I want to create a new matrix MatrixXf C with max values for each index i.e.

***C(i,j) = max(A(i,j), B(i,J);***

Does Eigen have a function to do this?

Comment: `A.cwiseMax(B)` or `A.array().max(B.array())` If you're familiar with Matlab, here's a cheat-sheet: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/AsciiQuickReference.txt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element-wise max and positive part in Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485794/element-wise-max-and-positive-part-in-eigen)

Comment: I was actually trying to convert a MATLAB code to C++. Your comment did help me. Thank you Mr. Pranav!!

Answer (score 1):

A.cwiseMax(B) can also be used.

Check http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html#title6 for reference

Comment: Thank you Mr.Vibhuti!!